# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies

Tags: android, expo, google-play-console

i'm having some problem on sending my app to production in play store

See, the first time i tried to send my app to production i received an email 3 days later with this:

> After a recent review, we found that your app --- (---) is not
> compliant with one or more of our Developer Program Policies. See
> below for more information about your app’s status and how to correct
> the issue.
>
> **Issue with your app**
>
> **Issues with submitted video**
>
> We were unable to view the video you provided in your declaration.
>
> Your video should show the in-app feature’s functionality showing
> usage of location in the background, and how a user would trigger the
> prominent disclosure, runtime permission (with user consent), and
> feature in action.
>
> Please check that your video is accessible, and/or modify your video
> to demonstrate the declared feature that requires access to location
> in the background, then resubmit your declaration form via the Play
> Console. Affected APK(s): APK:7, APK:1

And i noticed this:

> Your video should show the in-app feature’s functionality showing
> usage of location in the background

**Note: i created my app using react native and expo**

So i realized that expo, by default, includes a lot of permissions in my app, hence, i decided to create a new build including only the permissions my app really needs. (Removing the background location)

- ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Then uploaded my app to play store and sent it to production on monday and today i received the same email saying my app was rejected by the same reason mentioned above.

After reviewing the email i read this: **"Affected APK(s): APK:7, APK:1"**

And my current app version is **APK: 8** which means that i must edit all these versions

So the thing here is that i don't know how to change the code of the previous versions of my app.

What can i do to solve this? any suggestions

Comment: `What can i do to solve this?` you have to comply with the policies set out by google, nothing really we can help you with here

Comment: @a_local_nobody thanks for your helpful answer.

Comment: i'm sorry that it's not the answer you want to hear, but that's the reality of asking about how to fix a specific policy, you just have to comply with it, there really isn't anything we can do for you here

Comment: I have the same issue, I don't use the background location service, but google play tells me I do. I don't understand.

Can you solve this? Thanks!

Comment: i got same issue. i think google team check the wrong version because i already upload the new apk version.

Answer (score 1):

I think your video is not accessible or it is in private mode,

Google says for videos you can save it either you drive or youtube but when you put the video from your google drive you need to make it public other vises it will not able to access and then google will not allow to process it. your video should not have any copyright issues and also make the video that explains everything in a clear manner so that it would not creating any problem.

in my case I also got this type of alert then I follow the steps that google listed and make proper explainer video.

Comment: I will try to make it like you say.. thanks man!

Comment: SANJEEV, indeed, my video was private but now i set it to hidden so they can access using the url and i already changed the video url from play store console, should i upload a new version of my app? can you provide me the steps you took once you did it, please

Comment: Were you able to solve it @Edwin